# Spyder/Pythonxy crashes

Tags: scipy, spyder, pythonxy

Upon installing python xy 2.7.5 on my laptop, I tried to launch the Spyder IDE. This yielded the following error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>spyder.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 9, in 
    load_entry_point('spyder==2.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'spyder')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 72, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 112, in 
    from spyderlib.plugins.ipythonconsole import IPythonConsole
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 31, in 
    from IPython.frontend.qt.kernelmanager import QtKernelManager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\qt\kernelmanager.py", line 9, in 
    from IPython.zmq.kernelmanager import KernelManager, SubSocketChannel, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\zmq\__init__.py", line 67, in 
    check_for_zmq('2.1.4')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\zmq\__init__.py", line 51, in check_for_zmq
    import zmq
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 35, in 
    _libzmq = ctypes.CDLL(bundled[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden
```

Using a python console, I was able to run python code as well as matplotlib and numpy code. Ipython works, however Ipython (Qt) does not work. what could be the reason for this?

The host OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a problem with the most recent builds of [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/), which are messaging libraries that are required for [IPython](http://ipython.org/), and not with Spyder itself. The latest zeromq builds are not compatible with Win XP. This is a know issue with recent versions of Python(x,y) on Win XP which can be solved by following the guidance in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=670).

Answer (score 0):

It works by installing
https://pythonxy.googlecode.com/files/pyzmq-13.0.2-4_py27.exe
and
http://h5py.googlecode.com/files/h5py-2.1.3.win32-py2.7.msi
,

As it is posted in http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=670